# Access locked files from Windows XP

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice, windows-xp, encoding, data-recovery

Because of a problem in an XP computer I had to use Ubuntu Live CD to access and save data to an external USB drive. Now, some of the folders in the USB can be accessed without any problem but some of them not. Any file in this folder starts with "locked-" and ends with a strange extension.

The output of `ls` command is:

```
-rw------- 1 paco paco  19968 may 19 19:02 locked-Xiquets.doc.riwd
-rw------- 1 paco paco  19968 may 19 19:02 locked-REUNIO-2.doc.xybe
-rw------- 1 paco paco  27136 may 19 19:02 locked-RESUMEN DEL MOVIMIENTO DE LA CUENTA DE LA C0MUNIDAD DE PROPIETARIOS DE BUENAVISA.doc.zxuq
-rw------- 1 paco paco  19968 may 19 19:02 locked-prueba 1.doc
-rw------- 1 paco paco  25600 may 19 19:02 locked-naranjas.doc.gbwx
-rw------- 1 paco paco  25600 may 19 19:02 locked-Movimiento de las cuentas de la COMUNIDAD.doc.prfo
-rw------- 1 paco paco 321536 may 19 19:02 locked-INSTRUCCIONS-RADIO.doc.wfgm
-rw------- 1 paco paco  24064 may 19 19:02 locked-finca casa.doc.yhaf
-rw------- 1 paco paco  30720 may 19 19:02 locked-contrato asador.doc.rkyl
-rw------- 1 paco paco  26624 may 19 19:02 locked-contrato asador 2010.doc.nsbx
-rw------- 1 paco paco  30208 may 19 19:02 locked-contabilidad escalera.xls.brhd
-rw------- 1 paco paco  73216 may 19 19:02 locked-COM ARA TU DE QUI ERES.doc.acwr
-rw------- 1 paco paco  19968 may 19 19:02 locked-AVISO A TODOS LOS VECINOS.doc.zuli
-rw------- 1 paco paco  19968 may 19 19:02 locked-apendre a archivar.doc.begs
-rw------- 1 paco paco  25088 may 19 19:02 locked-ACTA COMUNIDAD.doc
```

I have tried to just remove the .XXXX extension but then LibreOffice can't properly open files. It asks for encoding but ISO-8859 and UTF8 give error in opening the file.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
Output of `mount`:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/48C1DA7909338E77 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

Renaming JPG files does not work:

```
paco@xubasco:/media/48C1DA7909338E77/papa/FOTOGRAFIA/CUADROS$ mv locked-CUADROS_120.JPG.fpyq CUADROS_120.JPG
paco@xubasco:/media/48C1DA7909338E77/papa/FOTOGRAFIA/CUADROS$ display CUADROS_120.JPG
display: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x60 0x32 `CUADROS_120.JPG' @ error/jpeg.c/EmitMessage/236.
```

Output of `lsattr`:

```
paco@xubasco:/media/48C1DA7909338E77/papa/FOTOGRAFIA/CUADROS$ lsattr locked-CUADROS_090.JPG.gfml
lsattr: Not implemented function while reading flags on locked-CUADROS_090.JPG.gfml
```

I had to translate from Spanish, sorry.

Comment: What was the issue you were having on the XP computer, and what tools did you use to recover the files? Were these files "locked" when on the XP drive, or did it happen when they were moved to the external hard drive? My guess is that this has something to do with what broke your XP box, but I am unsure.

Comment: Hi, the issue with the XP computer (not actually mine) is a known trojan that blocks access to the computer. I am asking for help to remove it to the antivirus program help forum but it is not easy. It only actually shows a screen where you are asked to pay to unlock your computer. To save data I have just started Ubuntu and saved to the hard drive. All folders copied are in the computer data partition, supposedly the trojan is in windows start, not in data partition.

Comment: Another curious thing is that in the photo folder some subfolders show pictures (jpg) without any problem and some others also show "locked files". Maybe I have to separately save the different folders to keep data safe?

Comment: If you rename the "locked" .jpg files, can you open those? Maybe libreoffice just can't open those .docs, because you need a language pack or something. My best guess is that the Trojan didn't really do anything but rename all the files to try and get you to pay.

Comment: What is the output to `mount`? Please add the output to your question and if possible point out which line is the drive with the problematic files on it. Also add the output for `lsattr` from the files in the directory.

Comment: Renaming jpg files does not work.

Comment: Added lsattr and mount output

Comment: I think you don't have to manually translate from spanish if you prefix your commands with `LANG=C`. Eg. `LANG=C lsattr`. Why is there a `fuseblk`? Is that standard for an NTFS filesystem? Anyone?

Comment: What is the output for eg. `file locked-CUADROS_120.JPG.fpyq`

Comment: paco@xubasco:/media/48C1DA7909338E77/papa/FOTOGRAFIA/CUADROS$ LANG=C lsattr locked-CUADROS_119.JPG.yufa
lsattr: Function not implemented While reading flags on locked-CUADROS_119.JPG.yufa

Comment: Don't know about fuseblk. I use this disk usually in Ubuntu but sometimes also in Windows

Comment: Don't worry about the error thrown by lsattr. What is the output to `file locked-CUADROS_120.JPG.fpyq` `fuser locked-CUADROS_120.JPG.fpyq` and when installed `lsof locked-CUADROS_120.JPG.fpyq`?

Comment: LANG=C file locked-CUADROS_119.JPG.yufa
locked-CUADROS_119.JPG.yufa: data                 

fuser and lsof gives no output

Comment: It sounds like the trojan encrypted the files, so unless you can find someone that has reverse engineered this trojan and figured out how it works, you're out of luck.

Comment: Related: [Microsoft's page on how to deal with ransomware](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/security/resources/ransomware-whatis.aspx)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. If you solved it, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). If the question no longer applies you may voluntarily delete/close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was not an Ubuntu based solution. The problem came from a virus in the computer. The only solution was to use some tools from the antivirus supplier that didn't perform exactly as needed. Not a good solution but a solution.